# Reverse of a doubly circular linked list having one element

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, circular-dependency

[image]

I have a doubt that  if we have a doubly circular linked list having one node (i.e.) head, and if i write `head.next = NULL`, then will `head.prev` also point to `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `head.next = NULL`, then it would look like below:

[image]

`head.prev` still points to `head` as shown in your post.

Answer (score 1):

if `head.next = NULL`, it won't be changing the `head.prev`(it'll still, be pointing to `HEAD`

You can run the following piece of code to check out how it works. (C++ implementation)

```
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
    struct Node *prev; 
};
void insertEnd(struct Node** start, int value) 
{ 
    if (*start == NULL) 
    { 
        struct Node* new_node = new Node; 
        new_node->data = value; 
        new_node->next = new_node->prev = new_node; 
        *start = new_node; 
        return; 
    } 
  
    Node *last = (*start)->prev; 
  
    struct Node* new_node = new Node; 
    new_node->data = value; 
  
    new_node->next = *start; 
  
    (*start)->prev = new_node; 
  
    new_node->prev = last; 
  
    last->next = new_node; 
} 
int32_t main(){
    FastIO;
    struct Node* start = NULL; 
    insertEnd(&start, 5); 
    cout << start -> next->data << endl;
    cout << start -> prev->data << endl;
    start -> next = NULL;
    if(start->next) cout << "Next is Null\n";
    else cout << "Next is not Null\n";
    if(start->prev) cout << "Prev is Null\n";
    else cout << "Prev is not Null\n";
    return 0;
}
```